# Importing components in LESS (CSS) for Angular application

Tags: css, angular, less

I am new to Angular and Less and looking at Angular application that uses LESS style for CSS.

I know for a fact that specific CSS file `angular.less` is being loaded (tested changes in it).

But there is one CSS styling in the other file (`ContentFormatting.less` which is in the same folder) that is overriding some default Materialize components:

```
.FieldDisplayContent {
    /* override materialize list formatting */
    ul {
        list-style-type: disc;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 5px 5%;

        li {
            list-style-type: disc;
        }

    }
```

How to import/use this component inside `angular.less` file in order to show up in the browser (right now this styling is not being loaded to DOM - it is not showing by default - assuming this file is not being loaded...)?

Comment: See documentation here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure if I understand correctly - but is it possible to import only part of CSS instead of the whole file all at once (file that I see has 3k lines of code and I need only 10 - one style, not sure what are consequences to the whole styling if import the whole external CSS file).

Comment: Ah for that I think Less' [reference imports](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-atrules-feature-reference) may help you. It gives you control of what is actually being compiled from the imported file. So you could import `ContentFormatting.less` into your `angular.less` using a reference import.